# How can I do that in Latex

Tags: formatting, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to do this using Ti*k*Z package, but the problem is not exactly the same as I need as shown below
[image]

Comment: Hi there! Could you edit your question to show what you've tried so far, so that we have a starting point for how to help you? Additionally, it may help to edit your title to be more descriptive, so that people can more easily find and answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I give my approach to this diagram.

Using `TiKz`, you can read the code next.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,7) {\(\lbrace x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\rbrace\)};
    \node[right] at (0,4) {\(\lbrace x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\rbrace\)};
    \node at (0.5,1) {\(\lbrace x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\rbrace\)};
    \node[right] at (0.5,5.5) {\(f(x_4)\)};
    \draw[-latex] (0.5,6.75) -- (0.5,4.25);
    \node[right] at (1,2.5) {\(f(x_2)\)};
    \draw[-latex] (1,3.75) -- (1,1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above code produces exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: How can the position of the arrow launched from a specific element be calculated? Is it something experimental or is there a formula for it? @mauramz

Comment: In this specific case I have calculated the position of both arrows using trial and error, but you can use a command to get the position of every arrow.